# Finding the most frequent value of string using BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am aiming of finding the most frequent value and group them by user id using BigQuery. It should be able to count the number of language used for each user id and result should return the language that is highest. However, I found error saying that

```
No matching signature for aggregate function AVG for argument types: STRING. Supported signatures: AVG(INT64); AVG(FLOAT64); AVG(NUMERIC) at [3:5]
```

This is my code:

```
SELECT * FROM( 
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    AVG(Language) AS mean,
    APPROX_TOP_COUNT(Language, 1)[OFFSET(0)].value AS most_frequent_value
  FROM `language`
  WHERE Language IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY User_ID);
```

What should I change so the result will return the value of language preferred by the each user ID?

[image]

Stored producer:

```
 CASE 
    WHEN Preferred_Language in ('EN', 'English') THEN 'EN' 
    ELSE Preferred_Language 
END AS Preferred_Language,
```

Comment: provide sample of input data

Comment: added in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  User_ID,
  ARRAY_AGG(Language ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] most_frequent_language
FROM (
  SELECT 
    User_ID,
    Language,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM `project.dataset.language`
  WHERE Language IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY User_ID, Language
)
GROUP BY User_ID
```

Comment: If I plan to add stored producer like in the edited question. where should I put it ? Is it in the nested query?

Comment: if i correctly understood you - put it in inner select statement instead of language - meantime. if you have new question(s) please post them as new questions and don't invalidate existing one as it in most cases can invalidate the answer. and in any case it is hard to answer such follow up questions within the comments

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I think I got the answer now