# Find the most frequent value and avoid duplicates BIGQUERY

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using the query below found under this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62310171/finding-the-most-frequent-value-of-string-using-bigquery) (thanks to Mikhail Berlyant) and it works almost perfectly.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  User_ID,
  ARRAY_AGG(Language ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] most_frequent_language
FROM (
  SELECT 
    User_ID,
    Language,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM `project.dataset.language`
  WHERE Language IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY User_ID, Language
)
GROUP BY User_ID
```

The only challenge I am facing is when 2 languages, for instance, are used as frequently. Then a duplicate is created.
If the field `date` is added, would there be a way to select only the latest language used when 2 languages or more are equally used?

```
#standardSQL
    SELECT
      date,
      User_ID,
      ARRAY_AGG(Language ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] most_frequent_language
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        date,
        User_ID,
        Language,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt
      FROM `project.dataset.language`
      WHERE Language IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY 1,2,3
    )
    GROUP BY User_ID
```

Comment: not clear at which point duplicates are created - it is clearly not in the code originally provided as there is a `limit 1`. please clarify your use case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to have date in the group by statement, but the get the latest value for each language, right?
So you should get max(date) instead of having it in the group by.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  User_ID,
  ARRAY_AGG(Language ORDER BY cnt DESC, max_date desc LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] most_frequent_language
FROM (
  SELECT 
    User_ID,
    Language,
    max(date) as max_date,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM `project.dataset.language`
  WHERE Language IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY 1,2
)
GROUP BY User_ID
```